# Calling and addition function in python

Tags: python

is there any way that I could add the string of one function by calling from other function.

```
def sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(number):
    sum += (getDigit(number))  # sum should be in this function
```

this is calling function.

```
def getDigit(number)-> int:
    sum = 0
    for i in range (len(number)-2, -1, -2):
        digit = int(number[i])
        digit = digit * 2
        if (digit >= 10):
        digit = (digit % 10) + 1
        #sum += digit   this is the result i want in the above function
    return digit
```

this function returns digit, and i want to add all the digits from get digit function into sum function.
I commented the line, sum. So i want this sum in the first function.
thanks for looking

Comment: Sounds like your method is misnamed then - Is that function doing something of any use?  It seems to be doing a fairly arbitrary operation on the input,

Answer (score 1):

Instead return the `sum`:

```
def getDigit(number)-> int:
    sum = 0
    for i in range (len(number)-2, -1, -2):
        digit = int(number[i])
        digit = digit * 2
        if (digit >= 10):
          digit = (digit % 10) + 1
          sum += digit
    
    return sum
```

---

In your case, we can yield digits first:

```
def getDigit(number)-> int:
    sum = 0
    for i in range (len(number)-2, -1, -2):
        digit = int(number[i])
        digit = digit * 2
        if (digit >= 10):
          digit = (digit % 10) + 1
          yield digit
```

And use for loop to calculate sum:

```
for x in getDigit(NUMBER):
  sum += x
```

Comment: yeah we can do that but the requirement is that sum should be done in the function above.